# Data migration in opportunity object

Tags: opportunity, data-migration

Scenario:

Under opportunities, country and state were text fields, however with the client requirement I have changed country and state fields as picklist. Country being the controlling picklist and state the controlled picklist.

Here the country and state picklist are mapped to the country and state picklist under LEAD object, i.e. on conversion values of country and state from LEAD gets transferred to country and state in OPPORTUNITIES.

**Requirement**

**Data Migration for the existing opportunities from old fields (country and state text fields) to the new fields so that there is no loss of data**

Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: You just load old fields values into new.

Comment: can you please elaborate and explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Extract all the existing records from Opportunity where you have values in country and state text field. Now update the new country and state picklist fields with those extracted values and do update using data loader.

Comment: Thanks however I am pretty new to Salesforce, can you please explain step by step process to implement the above approach.

Comment: are you using custom fields in lead object for country and state?

Comment: yes , under lead, country and state are custom fields (picklists). country controlling picklist and state controlled picklist.

Comment: You can map custom picklist fields to custom field types of text, text area, and picklist (unrestricted), but not long text.

Comment: question is not about the mapping, its about how not to loose the data under the existing the text fields (country and state) under opportunities and migrate the data to new fields (country and state) which are picklists.

Comment: Download data loader, then export all the opportunity records where ever you have values in those two text field. Now in your exported sheet replace the field name with your new field name and save it. Now update the Opportunity records using data loader. But remember you picklist field should not be restricted, it might give you error if your text field contains values which are not present in picklist fiels.

Comment: The export I got from opportunities, under the country field/cloumn, the countries are listed in the two digit convention like US for United States, CN for China , IN for INDIA etc etc, (Note in Saleforce, under opportunities country is a text fields however they are being stored in 2 digit convention at the backen).
The new picklist field (country) have values like United states, China , India etc and not 2 digit convention. How should I deal with this?

Comment: then using some Excel formula you can convert these two digits into values like for US it is United States

Comment: Thanks I am using Vlook up formula to convert from 2 didgit to full country names, replace them in export csv and then update it in SALesforce